# innerHTML doesn't work, why?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I  want  set new  in span,

```
var email ='ss@ww.net';
document.getElementById('spanEmail').innerHTML='<a class="f14 bold rose" href="mailto:'+email+'>'+email+'</a>';
```

but  this way not working ,  but this working

```
document.getElementById('spanEmail').innerHTML='sample text>';
```

How replace this span content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing " the code should read:

```
document.getElementById('spanEmail').innerHTML='<a class="f14 bold rose" href="mailto:'+email+'">'+email+'</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks  for  all  quickly reply .

Answer (score 4):

You haven't closed your href attribute with a double-quote.

```
href="mailto:'+email+'>
```

Should be

```
href="mailto:'+email+'">
```